# Can't Format Date To String

Tags: php, laravel

i am trying to get some data from database inside a view

```
@php($mostread=DB::table('articles')->orderBy('view','asc')->limit(4)->get())

@foreach ($mostread as $item)

<span class="post-date">{{$item->created_at->format('M d, Y')}}</span>

@endforeach
```

Error : "Call to a member function format() on string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `DB`, it's returning an object instead of an `App\Article` instance. Therefore, the `created_at` property is not a Carbon instance.

You can use the following to retrieve the articles instead:

```
$mostread = App\Article::orderBy('view', 'asc')->take(4)->get();
```

If for some reasons, you want to use `DB`, you can parse the `created_at` string with Carbon:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('M d, Y') }}
```

Comment: it return with an error : "class 'Article' not found"

Comment: use App\Article;

Comment: use App\Article; will make the first code work, i am gonna use the first one. thx